# How to remove the "border-radius" of the navbar-inverse in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, css

Everything is pretty much in the question. With a classic navbar (not inverse) the navbar is white with no border-radius but now that it is inverse, I can't manage to remove the border-radius.

Here is a pic of what I have :

[image: Navbar border-radius]

Thank you very much

Alex

Comment: inspect the element, see which element has the `border-radius` property set, and override it in your css.

Comment: post the url of ur site

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and vote to reopen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
style="border-radius:none !important"
```

Comment: the same than Ranveer but in a css file... not inline

Comment: Can you share your code or make a fiddle?